# summation of numbers is coming incorrect in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

In python 2.7, i am adding below numbers in the given order(since i am getting, those data from db in the same order)

24.73+1+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+8
 summation is coming as 39.99999999999997
but actual answer is 40

any suggestion will be helpful. thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 1):

From the Python [documentation on floats](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html):

> Note that this is in the very nature of binary floating-point: this is
>   **not a bug in Python**, and it is **not a bug in your code** either. You’ll
>   see the same kind of thing in all languages that support your
>   hardware’s floating-point arithmetic (although some languages may not
>   display the difference by default, or in all output modes).

So, this is just the way floating numbers work. To get the results you are expecting, try using the [`decimal` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html).

```
>>> 24.73+1+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+8
39.99999999999997
>>> s = "24.73+1+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+.33+8"
>>> sum([Decimal(x) for x in s.split('+')])
Decimal('40.00')
```